# Hirb - "Too many fields.." only when loading from irbrc (not directly in console)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hirb

I'm trying to get Hirb setup in my console.

When i type:

```
require 'hirb'
Hirb.enable
```

My (rather large) table prints fine (with column names shortened). However, I want to automatically load this (and other gems) whenever i load up `rails c`, so i edited my `.irbc`

```
  if Rails.env
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'hirb'
    Hirb.enable

    require 'wirble'
    Wirble.init
    Wirble.colorize

    require 'awesome_print'
  end
```

When running the same command from the console (Account.all), i then get the error:

```
Too many fields for the current width. Configure your width and/or fields to avoid this error. Defaulting to a vertical table
```

Any ideas why? I really like Hirb, but am too lazy to manually include it everytime i load the console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to fix this. Turns out when i ran:

```
Hirb::View.width
```

in the console (after Hirb being loaded from `.irbrc`), I saw it was smaller than expected - so it seemed as though Hirb wasn't correctly detecing my console size.

I changed my `.irbrc` file to explicitly pass in these values:

```
require 'hirb'
Hirb.enable({:width => 155, :height => 500})
```

And all works as expected